# JFrame not updating after changing JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I was trying to make a little game for fun, and after making a main menu, I wanted to change the JPanel. I tried, but my JFrame stays frozen, staying with the last frame before chaning the JPanel!
Here is my code so far! (code simplified)

```
public class Window extends JFrame{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7797736947468761815L;
private JPanel panel;
private final int buttonX = 440, buttonY = 400;
private final Font buttonFont = new Font(Main.BORING_FONT.getFontName(), Font.PLAIN, 50);

public Window() {
    this.setSize(new Dimension(1080, 720));
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    loadMainMenu();
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
public void loadMainMenu() {
    panel = new JPanel() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2969332078282980016L;
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(Main.MENU_BACKGROUND, 0, 0, this);
            if(something){                  
                g.drawImage(Main.BUTTON, buttonX, buttonY, this);
            } else {
                g.drawImage(Main.BUTTON_HOVER, buttonX, buttonY, this);                 
            }
        }
    };
    panel.setPreferredSize(this.getSize());
}
public void loadGame() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5378871926271288617L;
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 1080, 720);
            g.drawImage(Main.CHARACTER, 540, 360, this);
        }
    };
    panel.setPreferredSize(this.getSize());
    this.removeAll();
    this.add(panel);
}
```

}

Comment: To start with, you really should be calling `super.paintComponent` before performing any custom painting.  Second, you should be calling `revalidate` and `repaint` on the `contentPane` of the `JFrame` after you change it's content.  Avoid calling `removeAll` on `JFrame`, this will remove the `JRootPane` which is used to manage the `contentPane` (and other elements), instead, use `getContentPane` directly or, preferably, use a `CardLayout`

Comment: Perfect, thank you it works!